# Why is my code looping and printing multiple times when I don't want it too?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have to create a program that reads a csv file and uses it does contact tracing for school.
But for some reason, while my code is printing the correct answer, its repeating it when it shouldn't.

Here's my current code:

```
import csv
import datetime


# function to change the month
def find(month):
    name_of_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(month, '%m').strftime('%b')
    return name_of_month


# using the three parameters the ones in 
# contact with the infected are found
def check_for_at_risk(name, day, address):
    with open('contacts.csv') as f:
        for line in csv.DictReader(f):
            # checking for people that were in same place on the same day
            if line['Date'] == date and line['Address'] == address:
                if line['User'] != name:
                    m, d, y = line['Date'].split('/')
                    m = str(int(m))
                    m = find(m)
                    print(line['User'], 'should stay at home ', end='')
                    print('for the next 10 days due to the trip', end='')
                    print(' to {}'.format(line['Address']), end='')
                    print(' on {}, {} {}'.format(d, m, y))
                    
                    
                    
# user's inputs
name = input('The person who was tested positive: ')
date = input('When was the test? ')

# use these inputs to find places the infected was
with open('contacts.csv', newline='') as f:
    for line in csv.DictReader(f):
        x = ''
        count = 0
        for i in date:
            if count == 0 or count == 2:
                x = x + '0' + i
            else:
                x = x + i
            count += 1
        if line['User'] == name:
            if line['Date'] == date or line['Date'] == x:
                check_for_at_risk(name, date, line['Address'])
            else:
                check_for_at_risk(name, x, line['Address'])
```

Here's the output I'm getting:

```
The person who was tested positive: Arthur
When was the test? 09/02/2021
Doreen should stay at home for the next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
John should stay at home for the next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
Doreen should stay at home for the next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
John should stay at home for the next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
William should stay at home for the next 10 days due to the trip to 04 Kim Circle on 02, Sep 2021
```

Repeating infinitely.
And here's what I should be getting:

```
The person who was tested positive: Arthur
When was the test? 09/02/2021
Doreen should stay at home for next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
John should stay at home for next 10 days due to the trip to 4 Arizona Street on 02, Sep 2021
William should stay at home for next 10 days due to the trip to 04 Kim Circle on 02, Sep 2021
```

Comment: `for i in date:`  That's going to loop 10 times, once for each letter in that string.  I'm not sure what you were going for there, but that line is clearly not right.

Comment: @GavinWhite if the solution was more than just fixing a typo, please post it as an answer

Comment: @smc89 I actually fixed it for the first problem which was simply changing 'day' in line 14 to 'date'. But I have now run into a similar problem on a hidden case as I am working in grok. Any ideas?

Comment: @TimRoberts it's meant to loop over each character in the date to check and make sure it's in mm/dd/yyyy format. It should convert it if its not in that format. Although, you are correct that is where my problem seems to occur.